# ffmpeg overlay two videos side by side issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm having an issue trying to place to videos side by side with ffmpeg. Heres the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg - i video1.mpeg - i video2.mpeg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2[left]    
;[1:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2[right];[left][right]overlay=main_w/2:0[out]" output.mpeg
```

and I keep get the error message:

Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "Parsed_overlay_2" of overlay not connected to any destination.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a programming question?

Comment: Well I'm calling ffmpeg from my program.

Comment: You should always include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiple inputs or `-filter_complex`, specify the streams that you want in the output file using `-map`.  In this case, add `-map "[out]"` before the output file name.  If you want audio as well then add another `-map` option for audio, e.g. `-map 0:a` to use the audio from the first input.